# ProcessesGridView Not Recognised

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading a book called "Professional ADO.NET 3.5 with LINQ" and when I want to execute one of the codes, Visual Studio cannot resolve "ProcessesGridView".
The code is :

```
ProcessesGridView.DataSource = procs;
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
<div>
        <asp:GridView ID="ProcessesGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 

        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

and the code behind file:

```
var procs = (from proc in Process.GetProcesses()
                     where proc.Threads.Count > 10
                     orderby proc.WorkingSet64 descending
                     select new
                     {
                         proc.ProcessName,
                         Memory = proc.WorkingSet64,
                         Threads = proc.Threads.Count
                     }).ToList();
        ProcessesGridView.DataSource = procs;
        ProcessesGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have an object with "ProcessesGridView" id in your form.

Comment: yes there is an id="ProcessesGridView" in the view file but no idea why cannot connect to code behind file.

Comment: I just copy/past the code in VS

Comment: Try to rebuild the solution.

Comment: What exactly is the exception? Please add aspx code to the question also.

Comment: Check that the gridview has a reference in the designer.cs file....

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1084) which explains and elaborates the concept of the designer code, and the code behind.

You would need to have an object named ProcessesGridView in your .ASPX designer file, such as the following;

```
   <asp:gridview id="ProcessesGridView" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true" 
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>
```

You would then need to bind the results to the grid view in your code behind, like the following;

```
 ProcessesGridView.DataSource = ds;
 ProcessesGridView.DataBind();
```

If the code doesn't compile try cleaning the solution and rebuilding again. See also the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**You can also check that the gridview has a reference in the designer.cs file**

```
protected global :: System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView ProcessesGridView;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems taht `ProcessesGridView` is a kind of UserControl. Do you have declared the user control with the name `ProcessesGridView` in WinForms or WPF? Do you have created an instance for `ProcessesGridView`?

If `ProcessesGridView` does not exists, it seems not to be declared.